# Is it possible to have full hard drive access with a snap?

Tags: snap

As I understand it, a snap has to declare which interfaces it needs access to and it is confined to those.

Looking at:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/interfaces/
there is no option for full system access.

I can appreciate that the secure confinement is very important, but I am looking to use snaps as an easy distribution mechanism for duplicity backup, which needs to be able to read all system files to back them up and write access to wherever the user wants the archive files saved.

I know that this is not the primary use case for snaps, but now that they can be used on multiple distributions and solve dependency issues, I'm exploring the idea as an alternative to having to generate all the different variants of our package.

Would we be able to bend snaps to our will, or is the format not really suitable for things that need that much access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I posted my question, Snapcraft has gained a new confinement option: "classic".

From: https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement

> Classic
>   Allows access to your system’s resources in much the same way
>   traditional packages do. To safeguard against abuse, publishing a
>   classic snap requires manual approval, and installation requires the
>   --classic command line argument.

Duplicity now has classic confinement approved and we have started building snaps in that way.

(See also: https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/pull/6436 which is about potentially adding a new interface for backup applications that only require read access to the whole filesystem.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, what you want is an interface that grants full access to a disk, and it's reasonable for such an interface to exist. It would not be an auto-connecting interface, in that either the user or the person who makes a device with the snap would need to explicitly tell the snap system to allow that connection to take place, but the interface itself is a reasonable request.

If you're game I'd suggest you work up a patch for snapd which we will shepherd into the code.

Comment: Many thanks, Mark. Good to know that even the SABDFL is not above doing FLS! Given it is you asking, I may just have a go at that. I'll follow Kyle's suggestion and try to put together a usable snap using --devmode first. If I can make that work, I can try to patch snapd to make it work properly. I did not want to spend the time making the snap if there was no scope for full disk access to be properly supported.

Comment: You're welcome, have a look at the existing interfaces, if needed chat with zyga or mvo in #snappy on freenode for pointers, and if needed ping me there too I will shepherd your patch in. Contributing an interface is a great way to help others, as you say, more apps will need this capability. See you on the snapcraft list :)

Comment: For anyone coming across this in the archives (it is still the top-voted answer at the time of writing), please see the new answer on --classic mode, which did not exist at the time I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this; you're essentially asking for your snap to be unconfined, which you get when installing a snap in devmode:

```
sudo snap install --devmode <snap>
```

You can still upload devmode snaps to the store, but they're a little more limited in how you share them with people (e.g. you can't place them in stable channels).

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I was aware of devmode snaps, but did not want the restrictions on sharing. I'm also not sure that I do want the application unconfined, as I am happy for them to be blocked from other interfaces (x11, pulseaudio etc). The only thing I need unconfined is access to the hard drive. 

As I understood it, snaps were slated to replace ppas in the long term. If so, I would expect others will need this interface created at some point.

Comment: If you get full access to the hard drive there's really no limit to the damage you can cause. SSH keys, passwords, other application's data, trusted session and system services, etc. Snaps may replace PPAs in the long run, but if they do so it'll be because they're an improvement on them, not because they share the same capabilities.